# subset dataframe with topmost values based on a category in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
Type    value
cellA   2.02
cellA   2.56
cellB   1.24
cellB   2.34
cellB   4.56
cellC   3.55
cellC   2.36
cellC   6.78
cellC   3.56
```

and I want to subset it based on the topmost value for each type,,, so the output would be

```
Type    value
cellA   2.56
cellB   4.56
cellC   6.78
```

How can I achieve this in R - does the unique command can be of any help -  I am bit struck::: Thanks for the suggestions

M

Comment: you can do `library(data.table);setDT(df)[,list(val=max(value)), type]`

Comment: Or just `aggregate(value ~ Type, df, max)` with just base R. With `data.table` I would go with `unique(setDT(df)[order(-value)], by = "Type")`

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr` this can be done with `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
# assume your data is in data frame df2
df2 %>% group_by(Type) %>% top_n(1)
```

you get

```
Selecting by value
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: Type

   Type value
1 cellA  2.56
2 cellB  4.56
3 cellC  6.78
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `dplyr` for this:

```
dat %>% group_by(Type) %>% arrange(-value) %>%  filter(row_number()==1)
```

but `top_n` definitely is better, but I hadn't come across that before.

Answer (score 0):

Use function aggregate.

Example:

```
x<data.frame(Type=c('cellA','cellA','cellB','cellB','cellB','cellC','cellC','cellC','cellC'),
value =c(2.02,2.56,1.24,2.34,4.56,3.55,2.36,6.78,3.56)
)
aggregate(value~Type,max,data = x)
```